# HankelTransform problem

Tags: integral-transforms

Somewhere in the following code there is a bug. The result should not be zero!

```
FunctionExpand@HankelTransform[Sqrt[r] Cos[r], r, k, 1/2]
```

I think the answer should be undefined or a message like 'integral does not converge'. The [definition of the Hankel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform) has an integral that should not converge in the case above.

Can you confirm it is a bug?

Version: 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

Comment: 1) The “bugs” tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not add this tag for new questions. It will be added when the behavior has been confirmed as a bug. 2) There is no question in your post. If your purpose is to report a bug, then please contact support@wolfram.com . We are not Wolfram and cannot fix bugs ourselves. Otherwise please clarify your question.

Comment: For instance, do you agree with the result of `HankelTransform` *before* `FunctionExpand`? Or is the result of the transform incorrect in your opinion?

Comment: @MarcoB I am trying to wrap my head around the Meijer G function that is the outcome of the `HankelTransform`. I think that the integral that defines the Hankel transform should not converge in this case ... but I am no expert.

Comment: Indeed, calculating it up to the definition of the  Hankel transform, `Integrate[r*Sqrt[r] *Cos[r]*BesselJ[1/2, r*k], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> k > 0]`, we obtain "Integrate::idiv: Integral of (Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] r Cos[r] Sin[k r])/Sqrt[k] does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}." and the returned input. Definitely a bug.